# Adding new row created_at field is filled with -3 hours difference

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.8 / mysql 5.7.28 under Kununtu 18 I have a problem that adding new row created_at field is filled  with -3 hours difference.
In my control :

```
public function add_hostel_enquery()
{
    $request     = request();
    $requestData = $request->all();

    $newHostelInquery                   = new HostelInquery();
    $newHostelInquery->creator_id       = ! empty($requestData['creator_id']) ? $requestData['creator_id'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->hostel_id        = ! empty($requestData['hostel_id']) ? $requestData['hostel_id'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->full_name        = ! empty($requestData['full_name']) ? $requestData['full_name'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->email            = ! empty($requestData['email']) ? $requestData['email'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->phone            = ! empty($requestData['phone']) ? $requestData['phone'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->info             = ! empty($requestData['info']) ? $requestData['info'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->start_date       = ! empty($requestData['start_date']) ? $requestData['start_date'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->end_date         = ! empty($requestData['end_date']) ? $requestData['end_date'] : '';
    $newHostelInquery->request_callback = !empty($requestData['request_callback']) ? "Y" : 'N';
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $newHostelInquery->save();
        DB::commit();
    ...
```

In config/app.php :

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Kiev',
```

and in my OS I have the same timezone .

Database is created as :

```
Schema::create('hostel_inqueries', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
    ...
});
```

I know Updating row I fix it issue with code:

```
$hostelInquery->updated_at = Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));
$hostelInquery->save();
```

How to make created_at filled on insert ?

Comment: In your migration, you're manually creating `created_at` and `updated_at`, but there's a function that can be used to auto-create both: `$table->timestamps();`. All that does is create both columns, but there's a slight difference in that both are `nullable()`. The `useCurrent()` might be messing with this (don't know what it does personally), so consider just using `$table->timestamps();`, and let Laravel handle these by setting `public $timestamps = true;` on your `HostelInquiry` model (assuming you have a Model for this table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use $table->timestamps() just as I prefer to set created_at server, 
So I found decision setting on mysql part :

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+3:00';
```

and checking :

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```